# Dell XPS M1730 flashing red green blue white black over and over

Tags: graphics, dell-xps

When I turn on my power button on my Dell laptop, the screen just flashes red green blue white black and then repeats that.

This happens as soon as the computer turns on. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: If I had to design an LCD test, that sounds like the perfect description. I'm going to guess dead video card on the machine. Plug in an external monitor and report back -- the folks on [su] will probably want to know the results. Maybe [iFixit](http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/search/dell) has pre-written guides for your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The video card was dead as well as other problems related to the keyboard. Dell was not clear in what the problem was. They sent me an Alienware to replace it.

Answer (score 0):

Dead video card is a common problem on the XPS M1730. Do you have warranty?